# JavaScript - using the users input as function call

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small javascript project. I'd like to receive a users console input and furthermore use the input to calculate some values.

I capture the users input in a variable called `answer`.

when using `console.log(answer)` the answer get printed.

let's say the user's answer was `MILK`

my current (working and hardcoded) call looks something like this:

```
let p = 0;
call.prices('MILKPRICE', (err, tic) => { p = tic.MILKPRICE; });
```

now I'd like to replace the word 'milk' with the user's answer

```
let p = 0;
call.prices(answer+'PRICE', (err, tic) => { p = tic.answer+'PRICE'; });
```

which returns undefined. is there a way to actually use the user's input and not hardcoding all possible records?

thank you very much

Comment: What is `call.prices` function? can you share the definition of this function?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to `call.prices`, however, it's mainly the issue that I cannot get `p = tic.answer+'PRICE'` this to actually use the user's input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I identify your code correctly you are trying to use the dot notation to access a key in an object. That methode, thought nicer to read and write does not support variables, however you can simply use brackets for accessing the field.

Like so:

```js
const prices = {
  MILKPRICE: 2,
  WATERPRICE: 1
}
const answer = "MILK"

// this will fail
console.log(prices.answer+"PRICE");

// this will work
console.log(prices[answer+"PRICE"]);
```

Comment: thank you! that did the job just perfectly fine.

`call.prices(answer+'PRICE', (err, tic) => { p = tic[answer+'PRICE']; });`